how to do a code first protobuf-net serialization/deserialzation?
I'm new to protobuf-net and am trying to use protobuf serialization/deserialization to store data on disk as a text file. My question is about the methods for serializing/deserializing data. I'm using a code-first approach and am a bit confused because, with a .proto file, the protoc compiler generates serializer/deserializer methods. What should be done in the case of code-first? Do I have to write these methods myself? How does protobuf help in this case compared to doing it manually?
Note: I'm not creating any RPC/GRPC servers or clients; I just need to serialize data into binary and store it on disk.
Thank You
I have tried to write the serializer/deserializer, it works to an extent but I am looking for information about the better ways to approach the problem given my almost no experience with protobuf-net.
